# VBS to ping a group of servers but not ping the group name

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to modify an existing VBscript that pulls server names from my different sites from a text document and then pings them, the servers are all grouped together by the site they are located at. The script then displays whether the server is online or offline in an excel page. This all works fine except that the script tries to ping the name of the site as well. The goal here is to mainly clean up my results by having the name of the site displayed in the excel file but not be pinged.
Here is my current VBscript

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add

intRow = 2

objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Machine Name"
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "On Line"
objExcel.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Off Line"

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("servers.txt")

Do While Not (InputFile.atEndOfStream)

    HostName = InputFile.ReadLine

    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Ping = WshShell.Run("ping -n 1 " & HostName, 0, True)

    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = HostName

    Select Case Ping
        Case 0 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "On Line"
        Case 1 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = "Off Line"
    End Select

    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

objExcel.Range("A1:B1:C1").Select
objExcel.Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
objExcel.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 11
objExcel.Selection.Font.Bold = True
objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

here is a copy of the text document.

```
DISTRICT OFFICE
Server A
Server B

LAB
Server LA

School 1
Server 1A
Server 1B

School 2
Server 2A
Server 2B

School 3
Server 3A
Server 3B
Server 3c
```

Comment: Where's a sample of your `servers.txt` file?  Does that include the site in it?

Comment: I edited the question to include a copy of the text document. Does this Help?

Comment: Do all line entries you want to ping start with the word School?

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. School, Lab, and "District Office" are the group headers, and you're trying to skip over the headers of the groups and only ping the servers listed under the group names.  The servers presumably don't have spaces in them.  Therefore, the question really is whether the header pattern can always be obviously distinguished from the server name patterns.  Am I right?  If so, the random sample data provided isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: You are correct. When the script runs and displays the excel file, I get an offline indicator for the group site as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another though, and simpler to implement would be case:

```
... OTHER CODE ...
HostName = InputFile.ReadLine
IF NOT(UCase(HostName) = HostName) THEN
  Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Ping = WshShell.Run("ping -n 1 " & HostName, 0, True)
  objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = HostName
  Select Case Ping
    Case 0 : objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "On Line"
    Case 1 : objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = "Off Line"
  End Select
End If
... OTHER CODE ...
```

To use this code, all you would need to do is upper case your group labels.  If you wanted to get fancy, you could include them in your spread sheet:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add

intRow = 2

objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Machine Group"
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Machine Name"
objExcel.Cells(1, 3).Value = "On Line"
objExcel.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Off Line"

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("servers.txt")

Do While Not (InputFile.atEndOfStream)
  HostName = InputFile.ReadLine
  IF NOT(UCase(HostName) = HostName) THEN
    Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Ping = WshShell.Run("ping -n 1 " & HostName, 0, True)
    objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = GroupName
    objExcel.Cells(intRow,2).Value = HostName
    Select Case Ping
      Case 0 : objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = "On Line"
      Case 1 : objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value = "Off Line"
    End Select
  Else
    GroupName = HostName
  End If
  intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

objExcel.Range("A1:B1:C1").Select
objExcel.Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
objExcel.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 11
objExcel.Selection.Font.Bold = True
objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just put some arbitrary character in front of all the group names in the text file and then use an if statement to make sure the line in the text file you are reading doesn't have that character.

For example, if I put a `~` in-front of the group names in the text file, I could then add the following change to your code to filter out the Group names:

```
...

Do While Not (InputFile.atEndOfStream)

    HostName = InputFile.ReadLine

    If Not (Mid(HostName, 0, 1) = "~") Then 'Checks the first character of the current line
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Ping = WshShell.Run("ping -n 1 " & HostName, 0, True)

        objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = HostName

        Select Case Ping
            Case 0 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "On Line"
            Case 1 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = "Off Line"
        End Select
    End If

    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

...
```

`...` indicates omitted code that was not relevant to the example.